# Amazon EC2 Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, amazon, ec2

Ребят, апач запустил postgresql запустил все но при переходе по моему (насколько я знаю ec2-18-188-148-10.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com) домену. Сайт не открывает вообще, Превышено время ожидания ответа от сайта ec2-18-218-90-238.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com. подскажите что может быть не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EC2 блокирует доступ по 80 порту по умолчанию. Откройте консоль EC2, Instances, выберите свою, найдите Security Group, перейдите в неё и там отредактируйте Inbound - добавьте TCP 80.

Comment: Успехов вам, огромное спасибо